# Travis-CI: S3 deploy script is not adding new files

Tags: jekyll, travis-ci

My ultimate goal is to be able to schedule posts on my Jekyll blog. I am using Travis-CI to deploy the contents of /_site/ to an S3 bucket whenever I commit to my master branch in Github.

The Travis-CI flow works as expected but for the fact that new pages that are not built and addd to the /_site/ directory unless I build my site locally and push the new /_site/ folder directly to master. The posts are present in /_posts/ but do not get build and added to /_site/ automatically as they should when the site is rebuilt daily.

My travis.yml file is below.

```
language: ruby
rvm:
- 2.3.3

# before_script:
#  - chmod +x ./script/cibuild # or do this locally and commit

# Assume bundler is being used, therefore
# the `install` step will run `bundle install` by default.
install: gem install jekyll html-proofer jekyll-twitter-plugin
script: jekyll build && htmlproofer ./_site

# branch whitelist, only for GitHub Pages
branches:
  only:
  - master

env:
  global:
  - NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=true # speeds up installation of html-proofer

exclude: [vendor]

sudo: false # route your build to the container-based infrastructure for a faster build

deploy:
  provider: s3
  access_key_id: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY
  secret_access_key: $AWS_SECRET_KEY
  bucket: $S3_BUCKET
  local_dir: _site
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out: the Travis-CI deploy gem doesn't include a build step. It just pushes the contents of the repo to S3. I updated my build script to push as part of the build and validation step.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the option [skip_cleanup](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/#uploading-files-and-skip_cleanup) as true on deploy directive